# Matrix minimization problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization

I have the following minimization problem:
$$\min_{||w||=1}\Big(w^{T}X^{T}Xw\cdot{}w^{T}Aw-2w^{T}X^{T}XAw\Big)$$
where $w$ is a $n\!\times\!1$ vector, $X$ is a $n\!\times\!n$ symmetric matrix, and $A$ is a $n\!\times\!n$ diagonal matrix. Is there a closed-form solution? If not, what kinds of iterative methods should I use to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\a{\alpha}\def\b{\beta}
\def\g{\gamma}\def\t{\theta}
\def\l{\lambda}\def\s{\sigma}
\def\L{\ell} \def\LP#1{\L^{#1}}
\def\bR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$Consider an unconstrained vector $u$ and how perturbations
affects its length
$$\eqalign{
\LP2 &= \|u\|^2 = u^Tu \qiq \L\:d\L = u^Tdu  \\
}$$
By constructing $w$ from $u$
$$\eqalign{
w &= \LP{-1} u \qiq w^Tw = \LP{-2}\LR{u^Tu} = \o \\
dw &= \LP{-1}du \;-\; u \LP{-2}d\L \\
 &= \LP{-1}du \;-\; u \LP{-2}\LR{\LP{-1}u^Tdu} \\
 &= \LP{-1}\LR{I - ww^T}du \\
}$$
the constraint can be eliminated, leaving a fully unconstrained problem.

For typing convenience, define the matrix variables
$$\eqalign{
B &= X^TX \\
C &= BA \\
S &= \fracLR{C+C^T}2 \qiq w^TSw = w^TCw \\
M &= \a B-AB \;+\; \b A - BA \\
  &= (\a I-A)B \;+\; (\b I-B) A \\
}$$
and the scalar variables
$$\eqalign{
\a &= w^TAw &\qiq d\a = 2Aw:dw \\
\b &= w^TBw &\qiq d\b = 2Bw:dw \\
\s &= w^TSw &\qiq d\s = 2Sw:dw \\
}$$
Rewrite the objective function and calculate its gradient
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \a\b - 2\s \\
d\phi &= \a\:d\b + \b\:d\a - 2\,d\s \\
  &= \LR{2\a B + 2\b A - 4S}w : dw \\
  &= 2\LR{\a B + \b A - AB - BA}w : dw \\
  &= 2Mw : dw \\
  &= 2Mw : \LP{-1}\LR{I - ww^T}du \\
  &= 2\LP{-1}\LR{I - ww^T}Mw : du \\
\grad{\phi}{u} &= 2\LP{-1}\LR{I - ww^T}Mw \\
}$$
Use this gradient expression in any [Gradient Descent](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent)
algorithm to numerically calculate the optimal $u$ vector,
after which the corresponding $w$ vector can be obtained by normalization.

Alternatively, one could set the gradient to zero to produce
$$\eqalign{
Mw = w\LR{w^TMw} = \l w \\
}$$
which ***looks*** like an eigenvalue problem,
except that $(\l,\,M)$ are both functions of $w$.

Nonetheless, a modified [Power Iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration) is another possible solution algorithm.

---

In several steps above, a colon is used to denote the Frobenius product
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \|A\|^2_F \\
}$$
This is also called the double-dot or double contraction product.

When applied to vectors $(n=\o)$ it reduces to the standard dot product.

The properties of the underlying trace function allow the terms in a
Frobenius product to be rearranged in many useful ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \\
A:B &= A^T:B^T \\
C:\LR{AB} &= \LR{CB^T}:A &= \LR{A^TC}:B \\
}$$